# How to compare only date components from DateTime and linq query

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I'm writing a C# application, where I need data from today to next 7 days,

in Linq. I wrote following thing

```
 var query = SelectedEquipBookings.Where(x => x.BookedFromDteTme >= DateTime.Now && x.BookedFromDteTme.Date < DateTime.Now.AddDays(7));
```

The problem is BookedFromDtetme contains: `12/3/89 11:22:12` time also, and `Datetime.Now` contains different time.

Please correct my query

Comment: Is this LINQ to Objects or EF/SQL? The solution will be different depending on the source of your data.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.Today` instead if you want today's date with time set to `00:00:00`.

```
var query = SelectedEquipBookings.Where(x => x.BookedFromDteTme >= DateTime.Today && x.BookedFromDteTme.Date < DateTime.Today.AddDays(7));
```

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
    using System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions;
    var query = SelectedEquipBookings.Where(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.BookedFromDteTme) >= DateTime.Now.Date && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.BookedFromDteTme) < DateTime.Now.AddDays(7).Date);
```